# How to remove html elements from a string

Tags: java, javascript, cleditor

BO:

```
class Apple {

private String appleName;

private String appleBenefits;

}
```

From the jsp, I am using a jquery editor plugin (cleditor.js) to type in the value of the field `"appleBenefits" from the jsp.`

```
String appleBenefits = "<ul><li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;An apple a day keeps the <hr><font color="ff0000">Doctor away</li></ui><br>"
```

However when I need to store its value in DB, I need to store it as:

```
"An apple a day keeps the Doctor away"
```

How can I do this in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jsoup for removing html elements from string and also for xss security

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer

and to just remove html, try this:

```
Jsoup.parse(html).text();
```

EDIT: thanks to [user2640782](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2640782/user2640782)

With this code the output will be "    An apple a day keeps the Doctor away". To get rid of the empty spaces in the beginning you can call like this: `Jsoup.parse(appleBenefits).text().replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ").trim();`

Comment: With this code the output will be `"    An apple a day keeps the Doctor away"`. To get rid of the empty spaces at the beginning you can call like this: `Jsoup.parse(appleBenefits).text().replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ").trim();`.